# Failed to read artifact descriptor for pom.xml in VSCode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a Java project in VSCode but I am getting this error:

```
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.6.4
    
    org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.6.4
/.../
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:pom:3.1.0 failed to transfer from https://repo.spring.io/release during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of spring-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:pom:3.1.0 from/to spring-release (https://repo.spring.io/release): Connect timed out
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:176)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1347)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:544)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:454)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1381)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:544)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:454)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:293)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:pom:3.1.0 failed to transfer from https://repo.spring.io/release during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of spring-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:pom:3.1.0 from/to spring-release (https://repo.spring.io/release): Connect timed out
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:425)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:172)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:pom:3.1.0 failed to transfer from https://repo.spring.io/release during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of spring-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:pom:3.1.0 from/to spring-release (https://repo.spring.io/release): Connect timed out
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:574)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:484)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:402)
        ... 45 more
    Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.1Java(0)
    /.../
    
    Missing artifact com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:jar:1.9Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.6.4Java(0)
```

I installed the latest versions of Maven and JDK and also added them to PATH and verified the installation, but no success in running the project. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: *Connect timed out* Looks like an network issue

Comment: @Jens I tried to load the project with and without VPN, but it didn't fix.

Comment: Any proxy configuration?

Comment: @Jens in vscode I did not define any proxy configuration, I checked my access to `https://repo.spring.io/release` which is mentioned in the error, I have access with browser

Comment: sounds like you need a proxy configuration

Comment: @Jens can you provide me a link about proxy configuration, I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Jens vscode does not use the VPN which is active on my system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked JAVA_HOME in my path, then I used `mvn -U clean install` in VSCode terminal. After reloading the window it is fixed

Comment: @JialeDu stackoverflow did not allow me to mark the answer at the time and said I will be permitted in 3 day and I forgot. I checked it now,

Answer (score 0):

I just delete the .**m2** folder on my PC then on my **pom.xml** I did change the version of my springboot into **2.7.1** then on VScode Terminal I did the **mvn -U clean install** command. Hope it helps.